# OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError OT_MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webrtc, opentok

i am working on opentok with nodejs. 
i use tokbox for one-to-one videochats between users. It works properly in chrome, but not working in firefox.

it give me error

> OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError OT_MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED: The selected
>   voice or video devices are unavailable. Verify that the chosen devices
>   are not in use by another application. (getUserMedia error:
>   NotReadableError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox can not open the same camera in different tabs. You'll need a second camera or set media.navigator.streams.fake to true in about:config which enables fake devices.